# How to upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to latest version

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, 17.04

In my PC Ubuntu 12.04 was installed and now it is broken. How can I upgrade to the latest version of Ubuntu?

Comment: See the close link that will show up soon on how to deal with this type of issues. short answer: make a backup of your own documents and re-install. Oh and you can make the backup from the live session in case your system is  "cracked".

Answer (score 4):

You are running 12.04 LTS, the last LTS version is: 16.04 and you can't go from 12.04 to 16.04.

You should first upgrade to 14.04 and then go for 16.04. However I suggest you to do a fresh install, many things has been changed since 12.04 so upgrade a broken system is going to bring you more problems.

You can use `sudo do-release-upgrade` to upgrade your Ubuntu.

Also read this:

[How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu#110483)

Comment: Upgrading a broken system is probably impossible (i.e. upgrade won't succeed).  And technically, this question is off topic, as 12.04 is EOL since April 28, 2017.

Comment: I didn't pay attention to 12.04 being EOL ;)